# How do I select a mesh face by the length of it's longest edge in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In my node tree I have a varied amount of mesh faces generated depending input values.

I want to be able to select all the faces over a specified size, (or select all the ones whose longest edge is over a specified length).

So far I've just been able to select based on the index of mesh islands as shown. Ultimately the goal would be to either delete those selected meshes or to change their material.

Any ideas on how to best do this?

[image]

Comment: to *"select all the faces over a specified size"* you can use the *Face Area* node if *size* is the face area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workable solution that captures the distance between two vertices of each face. then using a compare node I select anything greater or less than an input to select or deselect faces by those values.

I'd like to make a system with more precision and control but this works for now!

[image]